# What are all possible GitHub pull request review statuses?

Tags: github

I am developing an automation tool that deals with GitHub pull requests and need to find the full list of GitHub pull request review statuses but couldn't get that either on its own API documentation page or generally on the web.

Those I've already found include `APPROVED`, `CHANGES_REQUESTED`, `PENDING` and `DISMISSED`. Appreciate if someone can provide me the full list.

This refers to GitHub Enterprise version of 2.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the list of available statuses in GraphQL API docs. There is [the link](https://developer.github.com/v4/enum/pullrequestreviewstate/). I'm pretty sure that other APIs (for instance, REST) also support and provide the same list.

There is a snippet from the documentation:

> PullRequestReviewState
>
> The possible states of a pull request review. Values
>
> APPROVED
>
> A review allowing the pull request to merge.
>
> CHANGES_REQUESTED
>
> A review blocking the pull request from merging.
>
> COMMENTED
>
> An informational review.
>
> DISMISSED
>
> A review that has been dismissed.
>
> PENDING
>
> A review that has not yet been submitted.